# Customized Bootstrap constructor not working in Play! reusable blocks

Tags: java, playframework, twitter-bootstrap

I've defined in play framework a customized Bootstrap field constructor

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="control-group@if(elements.hasErrors) { error}">
    <label class="control-label" for="@elements.id">CIAO@elements.label(elements.lang)</label>

    <div class="controls">
        @elements.input

        @elements.errors(elements.lang).map { error =>
            <span class="help-inline">@error</span>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

It work as expected, except if I put fields in a reusale view block:
    @(editForm: Form[Azienda])
    @import helper._
    @import crudder.viewhelpers.html.bootstrap.f
    @implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(crudder.viewhelpers.html.bootstrap.f) }

```
@editFields() = {
    @inputText(editForm("descrizione"), '_label -> "Ragione sociale")
}

@main("Amministrazione - Aziende") {
         <!--This one use my customized block-->  
         @inputText(editForm("descrizione"), '_label -> "Ragione sociale")
         <!--This one don't work!-->  
         @editFields()

}
```

Any ideas on how to make the reusable block use my customized constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it appear this question is not so attractive, however I post a workaround I've found just in case it can be useful to someone else.

It appear that the implicit constructor is not visible inside the block, so I explicitly pass the constructor to inputText:

```
@(aziende: List[crudder.models.Persistent], editForm: Form[Azienda],id:Long)

@import helper._
@import crudder.viewhelpers.html.bootstrap.f
@Field = @{ FieldConstructor(crudder.viewhelpers.html.bootstrap.f) }

@editFields() = {

    @inputText(editForm("descrizione"), '_label -> "Ragione sociale")(Field,null)
}

@main("Amministrazione - Aziende") {
<!--This one use my customized block-->
@inputText(editForm("descrizione"), '_label -> "Ragione sociale")
<!--Now this work too!-->
@editFields()

}
```